# How to send keystrokes to WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, keyboard, webbrowser-control

I would like to simulate keystrokes within an embedded `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser`. Various techniques for simulating keystrokes are documented already here on StackOverflow, however they do not seem to work for the WebBrowser control.

Knowing that the control wraps another window/hwnd, I would have expected the following to work however it's not:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);

...

SendMessage(myWebBrowser.Handle, WM_CHAR, key, 0);
```

I am already using `SendMessage` to forward simulated keystrokes to other parts of the WPF application, and would prefer a consistent solution; however this is failing for the `WebBrowser`.

How can I forward simulated keystrokes to `WebBrowser`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to use `SendInput()` instead of `SendMessage()`.

**The import:**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, User32.Input[] pInputs, int cbSize);
```

For the additional types and constants see here: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html

For the expected behavior see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx.

**My virtual keypress method:**

```
private void VirtualKeypress(Key keyCode, bool shift, char keyChar)
{
    User32.Input[] inputSequence;
    if (keyChar == '\0' && keyCode == Key.None)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Expected a key code or key char, not both.");
    }
    else if (keyChar != '\0')
    {
        inputSequence = KeyboardUtils.ConvertCharToInputArray(keyChar);
    }
    else
    {
        inputSequence = KeyboardUtils.ConvertKeyToInputArray(keyCode, shift);
    }

    User32.SendInput(
        (uint)inputSequence.Length, 
        inputSequence, 
        Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(User32.Input))
    );
}
```

**I have two helper methods**, `ConvertCharToInputArray()` and `ConvertKeyToInputArray()`, which return an array of length 2 or 4 depending if we need to tell windows that the shift key is depressed. For example:

```
'A' -> [] { shift down, A down, A up, shift up }
```

while just

```
'a' -> [] { A down, A up }
```

.

Comment: Why not use SendKeys?

Answer (score 1):

You were so close!  The handle reported by WebBrowser.Handle is the outter most handle, while all of the input is directed to the inner most handle:

```
var hwnd = _browser.Handle;
hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell Embedding", null);
hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell DocObject View", null);
hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Internet Explorer_Server", null);

SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CHAR, new IntPtr(0x0D), IntPtr.Zero);
```

FindWindowEx definition from pinvoke.net:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
```

Highlighted is the WebBrowser control:
[image: Highlighted is the WebBrowser control]

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm only used to using this in VB6 but Try sending to myWebBrowser.object.Handle or myWebBrowser.object.HWND is what i see in VB6, but you probably have .Handle in your .net version.

try the .object and let me know how it goes!!

Answer (score 0):

I found I could do movement around an HTML form (Chrome Browser) from within a C# program by using sendmessage to the process #.

However, I couldn't insert text into an input field.  Tried most everything (from pure C#).

While hacking, I noticed I could pop-up a context editing menu while the cursor was on the input I was trying to set, and one of the items on the menu was paste!  **WhatDoYouKnow!**  I could interact with that!

Here are the codes I used, once I had tabbed to the input I wanted to set:

```
Clipboard.SetText("52118"); // from C#, put the input value onto the clipboard

chrome.SendKey((char)93); // char 93 opens pop-up menu that includes paste
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
chrome.SendKey((char)0x28); // down to the first menu item
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
chrome.SendKey((char)0x28); // down to the second menu item (paste)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
chrome.SendKey((char)0x0D); // fire the paste
```

Check here for the code used for the ChromeWrapper (Thanks for that!):

[Sending keyboard key to browser in C# using sendkey function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156913/sending-keyboard-key-to-browser-in-c-sharp-using-sendkey-function)

Answer (score 0):

You have have to use PostMessage instead of SendMessage, then it should work.

PS: 9 years late I know